# Stubbing protect_from_forgery in rspec for API specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, csrf-protection, protect-from-forgery

I'm building an api for my Rails app and would like to protect it from CSRF attacks, using `protect_from_forgery`. I'm writing request specs for the `ApiController`, and would like to write specs for the response I get when the CSRF in the request is invalid. My question is how do I stub the behavior of `protect_from_forgery` to mimic an invalid CSRF token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
allow(ApiController).to receive(:protect_from_forgery).and_return(false)
```